# Git remove all deleted elements

Tags: git, github

I've started using git yesterday. I found out that I can remove files by using the command `git rm`. But isn't that very complicated? When I use SVN and I delete a file in my Windows Explorer, I just have to commit the changes and the file will be removed in the repository. Are there any similar solutions for git? How do you handle git? And are there any tools I can use? I've downloaded git extensions but I've ended up in using command line.

Thanks for your answers

Filoe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using command line, type `git commit -a`, that will commit the deleted files as well!

Answer (score 0):

you can also *stage* all files changed, deleted or added (respecting the ignore rules) using

```
git add -A :/
```

and then inspect what will be commited with

```
git status
```

then commit with

```
git commit
```